# Pointing a gitlab install to a domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, gitlab

What I am trying to do is have a web url on another hosted domain, point to a gitlab omni install on another server, on another network. The crux, is that I don't want to work under an IP, but the IP should resolve into the subdomain pointed at it..

*If this isn't possible, and I need to set up something else to get to that, please say! I'm just trying to find out how someone else has done something!*

I have a server in a co-location space, which hosts my local gitlab install. lets say it is on ip 11.222.333.44

I’ve edited git.mysite.co.uk DNS A record to point to 11.222.333.44; was I meant to, I dunno.

This now makes git.mysite.co.uk basically forward to 11.222.333.44 (I think). What I’d like here is for the ip to not be shown, and git to appear to be traversable through the human readable domain.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this running? I might not be explaining it correctly.

I’ve edited the external url in gitlab.rb to point to git.mysite.co.uk too.

I’d also like to enable SSL, but one step at a time I think.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? And did you run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` after changing the external_url in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

Comment: Yes ran that, and git works fine when connecting by IP specifically in browser, or visiting git.mysite.co.uk.

What I am trying to do is instead of  _11.222.333.44/dashboard/groups_ it would resolve to _http://www.git.mysite.co.uk/dashboard/groups_

if that makes sense?

Comment: Do you get a 404 on that link then?, strange that it resolves the root but not any of its own resources? Might be worth reloading nginx too `sudo gitlab-ctl restart nginx`

Comment: Ahh yes, I do get a 404 if I go directly to git.mysite.co.uk/dashboard/groups

What I was hoping is that when i got to git.mysite.co.uk/ the address bar would not then switch to the ip address, and continue in the human readable form.